# How to store HQL result(list) into a String Variable in SpringMVC & Hibernate?

Tags: java, string, hibernate, spring-mvc, collections

For password changing form ,require to  match old password with new password.

I wants to retrieve Password from database as per username and store this password into an String variable to compare with new password.Or Is there any method in spring to compare this?

```
 String password = "";
Query que = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery(selectpassword);
    List <String>list = que.list();
    for (String srt : list) {
        password += srt;
    }
    System.out.println("Password ->" +list);
```

Result is like `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

How to solve this?I wants to Store this query result into String Variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is select password from table. Then hibernate Must be returning List where password index must be 0.

So U can say

```
List <Object>list = que.list();
ArrayList passwordList = (ArrayList)list.get(0)  

List<String> passwords = new ArrayList<String>();

for(ArrayList list :passwordList){
     passwords.add(list.toString());
}
```

Comment: Hope it helps. Feel free to ask doubts. @S dg

Comment: Can not understand  what had done in for each loop.Will you help me.@Kashish Verma

Comment: So when your query is Select password , username from table; Hibernate returns List<Object> data = que.list(); where data.get(0) -- > Should return ArrayList of passwords and data.get(1) should return usernames as AL. So in for loop i m just taking list object converting it into string and adding it to the passwords arraylist.

Comment: i understood.But facing error in for loop                                                      (passwordList)  Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to ArrayList @Kashish Verma

Comment: Just change it to Object     for(Object list :passwordList){
     passwords.add(list.toString());
}

Comment: After That same error in  ArrayList passwordList = (ArrayList)list.get(0) ;java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: please give me any idea.@ Kashish Verma

Comment: U just need to see when u say list.get(0) what it is returning. Just open the implementation and code accordingly. Or if u r using eclipse just place your cursor on the method and see method signature.

Comment: Just get the object list and see what u r getting.

Comment: The value is :-  Ljava.lang.Object;@382ca2aa @Kashish Verma

Comment: No i mean internally objects will have some class type object . In which class Object type your password is stored , u need to figure out and call toString() or cast it accordingly.